# Incorrect Syntax near '=' SSRS Report Builder 3.0

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

sorry if this has been asked and answered before but I have not been able to find an answer that solves me particular problem.

I get the following message when trying to run an ssrs query and I am not sure how to correct it. Normally the error refers to an extra space or whatever that can be picked up from copy and pasting but I can't find it if there is one and I'm not sure what else the problem could be. Here is the error message followed by the query. Any help/comments would be much appreciated

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder

An error occurred while executing the query.
Incorrect syntax near '='.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Incorrect syntax near '='. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 102)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=09.00.4060&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=102&LinkId=20476

------------------------------"

```
SELECT 
company.cmp_name
,commodity.cmd_code
,commodity.cmd_name
,IIF(vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.[Delivery Year]=@DeliveryYear, SUM(vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.Charge),0) AS [Revenue Current Year]
,IIF(vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.[Delivery Year]=@DeliveryYear-1, SUM(vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.Charge),0) AS [Revenue Prior Year]
FROM
company
LEFT OUTER JOIN vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails
ON company.cmp_id = vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.[Bill To ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN commodity
ON vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.[Order CMD Code] = commodity.cmd_code
GROUP BY
company.cmp_name
,commodity.cmd_code
,commodity.cmd_name
```

Comment: Can you run the query in SSMS?

Comment: `IIF` became available in SQL 2012.   It is not valid in 2008.

Comment: No, unfortunately it gives me the same error.

Comment: Sorry I missed tagged this it is 2012 I will get that changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an earlier-than-2012 version of SQL, try changing this:

```
,IIF(vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.[Delivery Year]=@DeliveryYear, SUM(vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.Charge),0) AS [Revenue Current Year]
,IIF(vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.[Delivery Year]=@DeliveryYear-1, SUM(vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.Charge),0) AS [Revenue Prior Year]
```

to this:

```
,SUM(CASE WHEN vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.[Delivery Year]=@DeliveryYear THEN vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.Charge ELSE 0 END) AS [Revenue Current Year]
,SUM(CASE WHEN vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.[Delivery Year]=@DeliveryYear-1 THEN vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.Charge ELSE 0 END) AS [Revenue Prior Year]
```

EDIT

And try changing this:

```
@DeliveryYear-1
```

To this:

```
CONVERT(nvarchar(7), CAST(@DeliveryYear AS int)-1)
```

Comment: Thank you for this however the example you provided now flags a syntax error near then

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.

Comment: What are the datatypes of `[Delivery Year]` and `@DeliveryYear`?

Comment: Please try adding `vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.[Delivery Year]` to the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: For the time being they are just nvarchar

Comment: Added to the group by clause with no luck

Comment: If they are nvarchar, then in the second line try casting `@DeliveryYear` to int so that the `-1` will be interpreted correctly.  (but then converting back to string so the comparison can be made)

Comment: Unfortunately still no luck. Based on the error message the error is being thrown on the first then and not the second.

Comment: Can you create a SQL Fiddle or other reproducible script?   I don't see an error in what you say you are executing.

Comment: I have never used sql fiddle myself but I will look into creating something.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to put the aggregation outside the IIF statement, like this:

```
SELECT 
      company.cmp_name
    , commodity.cmd_code
    , commodity.cmd_name
    , SUM(
        IIF(
            vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.[Delivery Year] = @DeliveryYear, 
            vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.Charge, 
            0
            )
        ) AS [Revenue Current Year]
    , SUM(
        IIF(
            vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.[Delivery Year] = @DeliveryYear - 1, 
            vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.Charge, 
            0
            ) 
        ) AS [Revenue Prior Year]
FROM
    company
    LEFT OUTER JOIN vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails ON company.cmp_id = vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.[Bill To ID]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN commodity ON vTTSTMW_ChargeDetails.[Order CMD Code] = commodity.cmd_code
GROUP BY
      company.cmp_name
    , commodity.cmd_code
    , commodity.cmd_name
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Nathan however that still causes the '=' error.

Comment: I tested, and it doesn't matter if the SUM is inside or outside of the IIF()